# Find the double integral of the function over the defined region

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral, jacobian

> Evaluate $\iint {(x+y)^2}  dxdy$ over the region in the first quadrant bounded by $x^2-y^2=a$, $x^2-y^2=b$, $2xy=c$ and $2xy=d$ where $0<a<b$, $0<c<d$.

I took $x^2-y^2=u$ and $2xy=v$ and tried to express $(x+y)^2$ in terms of $u,v$. Then I changed the variables using the Jacobian from $x,y$ to $u,v$ with the limits. However after evaluating the integral the answer specified in the book doesn't match. The answer is $(b-a)(d-c)/4$[image: my try][image: 2nd page]

Comment: In your last calculations line you almost get what you say is the solution (just what I got, too), yet somehow the first double integral is supposed to equal zero, as  $\;\frac14\int dudv=\frac14(b-a)(d-c)\;$ ... Perhaps theres a mistake in the solutions.

Comment: See Mathematica notebook [MSE_Q4823847](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/pfeifermaintal/Published/MSE_Q4823847.nb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either the original integrand or the provided solution is incorrect.

As you've shown, under your change of variables,

$$\begin{cases}u = x^2 - y^2 \\ v = 2xy\end{cases} \implies \begin{cases}x = \dfrac1{\sqrt2} \sqrt{u+\sqrt{u^2+v^2}} \\ y = \dfrac1{\sqrt2} \dfrac v{\sqrt{u+\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}}\end{cases} \implies dx\,dy = \frac{du\,dv}{4\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}$$

so the given integral (partially) evaluates to

$$\begin{align*}
\iint (x+y)^2 \, dx \, dy &= \frac14 \int_c^d \int_a^b \frac{v + \sqrt{u^2+v^2}}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}} \, du \, dv \\
&= \frac14 \int_c^d \left(b-a + v \log \frac{\sqrt{v^2+a^2}-a}{\sqrt{v^2+b^2}-b}\right) \, dv\\
&= \frac{(b-a)(d-c)}4 + \frac14 \int_c^d v \log \frac{\sqrt{v^2+a^2}-a}{\sqrt{v^2+b^2}-b} \, dv 
\end{align*}$$

and so on; you can confirm this result does **not** simplify to the expected answer.

On the other hand, notice that $x^2+y^2 = \sqrt{u^2+v^2}$; this is probably what the author meant for you to work with.